# "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: System memory 259522560 must be at least 471859200" after installing Java 1.8 32 bits

Tags: java, windows, maven, x86, 32bit-64bit

After installing Java 8 **32 bits** on my computer to perform an unrelated task, I get the above exception when running `mvn install` on my spark-scala project.

I am using IntelliJ and Java 8 of **64 bits** for this spark-scala project and the path variables to this 64 bit Java 8 sdk are correct in IntelliJ | Project structure, and also in the POM (I have the Java 8 64-bits sdk in a user folder).

The JAVA_HOME variable is also pointing to the correct 64 bit java sdk (when I execute `mvn --version` I get:

```
Java version: 1.8.0_265, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK, runtime: C:\Users\vcalabui\.jdks\adopt-openjdk-1.8.0_265\jre
```

which again, is the correct 64-bit Java sdk.

However, it seems that Maven is still using the 32-bit Java somewhere since I am getting the above exception and when I uninstall the 32-bit Java from my Windows the `mvn install` works fine again.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Do you fork a new JVM under the covers?

Comment: Not sure what forking a new JVM is but  I don't think so.

Comment: Starting another Java command inside your build.  If that is not launched from JAVA_HOME you might see t his.

Comment: Check your PATH environment variable. When installing the 32bit Java it may have inserted itself too far in the front.

Comment: Ty @Harald, that was it!